# Check one class attributes in another class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how I can check in one class another class attributes. In my example I want in my `Check` class to check if the class `Moving` has executed the method `Move`.

```
public class Moving
{
    public bool startedmoving = false;

    public void move()
    {
        startedmoving = true;
    }
}
```

```
public class Check  
{ 
    //Check if method move is has run)
    //If (Moving.move)
    //then do something. 
}
```

Comment: And which _instance_ of `Moving` should be checked?

Comment: I imagine you would want to use the `startedmoving` field, though I would recommend using a property instead of a field, and would probably name it `IsMoving` rather than `startedmoving`.

Comment: And we can assume that `if (instanceOfMove.startedmoving) { ... }` is _not_ what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Which [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)? I see none.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is what you want with proper C# norm.

```
public class Moving
{
    public bool StartedMoving { get; set; } = false;

    public void Move()
    {
        StartedMoving = true;
    }
}
```

```
Moving example = new Moving();

if (!example.StartedMoving)
{
    example.Move();
}
```

Also concider checking [Abstraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract), it could be a good practice for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The link points to the `abstract` keyword. Can you clarify how this is relevant here please?

Comment: yeah good point maybe it was unclear, and i'm probably wrong on what he's trying to achieve. But the behaviour he's trying to implement is kinda generic, and worth inherating instead of implementing it whenever he needs it. For example `Moving` could inherit from something like `Runnable` that already implements `Run` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `event`: `Moving` fires `Moved` event, when `Check` handles it

```
public class Moving
{
    public bool startedmoving = false;

    public void move()
    {
        EventHandler moved = Moved;

        startedmoving = true;

        if (moved != null)        
           moved.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public event EventHandler Moved;
}

...

public class Check  
{ 
    private Moving m_Moving;

    private void onMoving(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Will be executed on every m_Moving.move() call     
    }

    public Check() 
    {
        m_Moving = new Moving();
        m_Moving.Moved += onMoving;
    } 
}
```